# How translate button value with i18next?

Tags: i18next

Using

```
data-i18n="content.mytranslation"
```

The translation goes to the end of ">" of the button.

How can I translate the button value?

Comment: Have the solution: data-i18n="[value]content.mytranslation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data-i18n="[value]content.mytranslation" to insert value in button. You can change any element attribute using "["  "]"